# How to pass search parameters to other pages when using pagination in php?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a search block in my site, that has multiple options that user can search upon them. It works fine, but how can I pass search parameters to other pages when using pagination in php?

I don't think that create form with hidden inputs of search parameters will be ok.

Comment: Use SESSION for this

Comment: You can use COOKIES too....

Comment: [Please try to improve your spelling.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/my-question-was-downvoted-closed-because-it-was-full-of-grammatical-mistakes-wh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sessions as

```
$_SESSION['search_string']=$searchstring;
```

concatenate the to be search string in a variable or if a single searching is to be done pass it with same session variable to other pages.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing by going to another page is [decoupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)).
You need a way to carry data along. You can use sessions or cookies.

Why don't you try jquery pagination against php pagination it will be more faster and may solve your problem by coupling the search parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You have, almost, two solutions:

SOLUTION 1:
Use cookies or session.

SOLUTION 2:
Autogenerate hidden inputs.

If you form and pagination is POST method:

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="'.$key.'" value="'.$value.'">';
?>
```

If you form and pagination is GET method:

```
<?php
$link = './?page='.$next_page_number;
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)
    $link .= '&amp;'.$key.'='.url_encode($value);
?>
```

Maybe you need mofidy some url or fields for correct pagination.

Regards...